# Delete Duplicates when Merging DF

Tags: r, merge

I know, I know.... Another merging Df question, please hear me out as I have searched SO for an answer on this but none has come.

I am merging two Df's, one smaller than the other, and doing a left merge, to match up the longer DF to the smaller DF.

This works well except for one issue, rows get added to the left (smaller) df when the right(longer) df has duplicates.

An Example:

```
Row<-c("a","b","c","d","e")
Data<-(1:5)
df1<-data.frame(Row,Data)

Row2<-c("a","b","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
Data2<-(1:9)
df2<-data.frame(Row2,Data2)

names(df2)<-c("Row","Data2")

DATA<-merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "Row", all.x = TRUE)

>DATA
  Row Data Data2
1   a    1     1
2   b    2     2
3   b    2     3
4   c    3     4
5   d    4     5
6   e    5     6
```

See the extra "b" row?, that is what I want to get rid of, I want to keep the left DF, but very strictly, as in if there are 5 rows in DF1, when merged I want there to only be 5 rows.

Like this...

```
  Row Data Data2
1   a    1     1
2   b    2     2
3   c    3     4
4   d    4     5
5   e    5     6
```

Where it only takes the first match and moves on.

I realize the merge function is only doing its job here, so is there another way to do this to get my expected result? OR is there a post-merge modification that should be done instead.

Thank you for your help and time.

Research:
[How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

[deleting duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655832/deleting-duplicates)

[Merging two data frames with different sizes and missing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225409/merging-two-data-frames-with-different-sizes-and-missing-values)

Comment: In the case of multiple matches do you want a specific one? That is, do you want to only take the first match?

Comment: @MikeH. Yes that would be perfect if it only took the first match

Comment: or `DATA <- merge(x = df1, y = df2[!duplicated(df2$Row), ], by = "Row", all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: @bouncyball Put that as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use the [`duplicated`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/duplicated.html) function as follows:

```
DATA[!duplicated(DATA$Row),]

  Row Data Data2
1   a    1     1
2   b    2     2
4   c    3     4
5   d    4     5
6   e    5     6
```

Answer (score 3):

It´s possible also like

```
merge(x = df1, y = df1[unique(df1$Row),], by = "Row", all.x = TRUE)
#  Row Data.x Data.y
#1   a      1      1
#2   b      2      2
#3   c      3      3
#4   d      4      4
#5   e      5      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only want the first row and don't care what variables are chosen, then you can use this code (before you merge):

```
Row2<-c("a","b","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
Data2<-(1:9)
df2<-data.frame(Row2,Data2)

library(dplyr)

df2 %>%
  group_by(Row2) %>%
  slice(1)
```